# django-registration POST 405

Tags: python, django, django-registration

I have moved login form into my base.html and I added this line to my template tag to make the login form work.:
`login(request, template_name='base.html')`
It works in my links and the auth links but it doesn't work with django-registration's links such as `/accounts/registration/complete/`. I want to make them work but I couldn't figure out why it's not working. How can I fix it? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I changed django-registration's template views to specific views and it works now.